# What are the drawbacks to bridging phases in my home electrical?

Tags: electrical

I'm installing some powerline automation equipment and I can't (for obvious reasons) control equipment that are on the opposite phase as my controller.

I've [found a phase coupler](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/150386274873?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649#ht_2612wt_1173), but I'm wondering if I will run into any issues or drawbacks from doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard practice to install a phase coupler. You should not have any issues.

Comment: does this include my energy bill? I don't want any unnecessary spikes ;-)

Comment: It will not spike your energy bill. The only problem you might have is if you install it incorrectly. If you are already installing switches and outlets correctly you should have no issue installing a phase coupler.